# Sparklyr, spark_read_csv, do we have to reimport data everytime?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

i'm using sparklyr to read data on my local machine.

What i did

```
spark_install()


config <- spark_config()
spark_dir = "C:/spark"

config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-java-options` <- paste0("-Djava.io.tmpdir=", spark_dir)
config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "4G"
config$`sparklyr.shell.executor-memory` <- "4G"
config$`spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` <- "1g"

sc = spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)

my_data = spark_read_csv(sc, name = "my_data", path = "my_data.csv", memory = FALSE)
```

After it is finished, in the folder `C:/Spark` i found a file named 
`liblz4-java8352426675436067796.so`

What's this file?

If i disconnect Spark connection, this file is still there. Next time if i want to work on `my_data.csv` again, do i need to rerun `spark_read_csv`? 
It takes long time to just read the data.

Or is there some way i could directly use this file `liblz4-java8352426675436067796.so`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After it is finished, in the folder C:/Spark i found a file named  liblz4-java8352426675436067796.so
>
> What's this file?

The file is a shared library of Java bindings for `liblz4`. It is not related to your data.

> If i disconnect Spark connection, this file is still there. Next time if i want to work on my_data.csv again, do i need to rerun spark_read_csv?

Yes you will have to re-import the data.`spark_read_csv` creates only temporary bindings which cannot outlive corresponding `SparkSession`.

If you want to keep the data you should create a persistent table using Hive metastore.